# Modify solr host and port for Spring Boot actuator heath check

Tags: solr, spring-boot

I have my solr server running on a different host and port then the traditional. Is there a way to configure them through the application.properties file, so that my health returns the correct status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solr health indicator uses the auto-configured `SolrServer` instance to check Solr's health. You can configure its IP address/hostname and port, etc using the `spring.data.solr.host` property. For example:

```
spring.data.solr.host=http://192.168.1.2:3456/solr
```